# Which client secret should be used fro webhook authentication in Intercom webhook

Tags: webhooks, intercom

We do have our app published in intercom store and our customers gonna use that app to install / use it to interact with our system, we do ask customers to configure the our endpoint under webhook for interaction purpose. I do have questions, as per this documentation https://developers.intercom.com/docs/references/webhooks/webhook-models/#signed-notifications they mentioned “your app’s client secret” do that mean client secret of published app or we should get customer’s intercom workspace app’s client secret

Answer (score 0):

In above scenario the published app's webhook URL and App's client secret will be used